# Why is my Hash not a Hash?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm mystified. I have the following method:

```
def coerce(value)
  case value
  when Hash
    from_hash(value)
  when Money
    value
  else
    fail ArgumentError.new "#{value.inspect} (#{value.class}) cannot be coerced into Money [ #{value === Hash}, #{value.class == Hash} ]"
  end
end
```

When called (deep in my application), it fails with this message:
`{:currency=>"DKK", :amount=>1000} (Hash) cannot be coerced into Money [ false, false ] (ArgumentError)`

What's up? My initial suspicion which turned out to be wrong, was that somewhere in the code, a library was calling `#with_indifferent_access` resulting in something that looked like but wasn't quite a Hash. But calling `#class` on the return value of `#with_indifferent_access` results in `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't know how to help you without a reproducible failing test

Comment: That's weird. But we definitely have not enough information to debug this. MCVE will help.

Comment: At this point, I close vote for not being reproducible.

Comment: `Hash === value` if you want to test it with `===`, not the other way around

Comment: Your test comparison in the output is around the wrong way for `case`. `#{Hash === value}`.. gah, beat me to it.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, mtm: definitely something else is going on there. http://pastebin.com/WLFNq5be

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Just noting that `value === Hash` is not testing the way `case` is.  If `Hash === value` is also false, then I'd suggest someone has messed with [Case Equality](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Short answer is that you should write

```
# ...
when ::Hash
# ...
```

instead of

```
# ...
when Hash
# ...
```

Longer story:

Turns out that because my method was in a class that inherited from `Virtus::Attribute` and because there is a `Virtus::Attribute::Hash` class, I was unwittingly trying to compare `value` with that beast instead of Ruby's own native Hash.

Comment: should have posted a better question esp. if answering yourself ... no notion of `Virtus` in the question!

Comment: @kares I don't understand your downvote at all. Obviously if I had known the answer to begin with, I could have asked the question in a way that made it easy to answer, but then I wouldn't have needed to ask the question to begin with! Other people may find themselves in the same situation of having a constant inside a module or a class shadow a top-level constant which can be very confusing, especially if they are not themselves authors of the class or module. Hopefully my answer will be able to provide them with a clue.